# Merging two files in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two files with information. I need to merge / join the rows from both files that are identical in a given column.

File A:

```
#chr    #start  #end    #gene   #0  #strand
chrM    3307    4262    MT-ND1  0   +
chrM    4470    5511    MT-ND2  0   +
chrM    12337   14148   MT-ND5  0   +
```

File B:

```
#chr    #start  #end    #gene   #0  #strand #e_chr #e_start #e_end      #e_id                      #0   #strand
chr1    12337   14148   MT-ND5  0   +   chr1    161427010   161427243   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9704  0   .
chr1    3307    4262    MT-ND1  0   +   chr1    161423805   161424053   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9703  0   .
chr1    4470    5511    MT-ND2  0   +   chr1    161429385   161429489   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9705  0   .
```

My result output should look like (essentially File B sorted similarly to File A):

```
#chr    #start  #end    #gene   #0  #strand #e_chr #e_start #e_end      #e_id                      #0   #strand
chr1    3307    4262    MT-ND1  0   +   chr1    161423805   161424053   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9703  0   .
chr1    4470    5511    MT-ND2  0   +   chr1    161429385   161429489   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9705  0   .
chr1    12337   14148   MT-ND5  0   +   chr1    161427010   161427243   Larp7-Chip.MACS2_peak_9704  0   .
```

I tried using `pandas.DataFrame.merge` to do this by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

FileA = pd.read_table("FileA.txt")
FileB = pd.read_table("FileB.txt")

results = FileA.merge(FileB, how='left', left_on='gene', right_on='gene')
results = results.dropna()
```

This seemed to work at first, but some of the rows are missing. File A has 19,000 rows, and File B has 4,800 rows. But my output file only has about 3,8k, when I expect it to have 4,800. What am I doing wrong? Is there any easier way to do this? I'm new to python.

Comment: This will depend on the actual values in 'gene' in your files. I'd suggest that you cut down the files to a few lines (say 20 each) and look at it again. If the problem remains unsolved, post the data.

Comment: I have finished the Python course at Teamtreehouse. The syntax is not the problem. My job involves tons of tab delimited file processing, which I usually do in R. I am attempting to do the same in Python using Pandas. Is that a problem?

@tfv i'll give that a shot

Comment: How many recs are you dropping via `.dropna()`?  I would start there.

Comment: following your description you should be using `how='right'` or, alternatively:  `FileB.merge(FileA, how='left', on='gene')`

Comment: @MaxU could you explain to me why this worked and not my other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your description you should be using `how='right'` or, alternatively: `FileB.merge(FileA, how='left', on='gene')`

Explanation:

```
In [171]: a
Out[171]:
   id col1 col2
0   1    a   aa
1   2    b   bb
2   3    c   cc
3   4    d   dd
4   5    e   ee

In [172]: b
Out[172]:
   id col1 col2
0   2    x   xx
1   4    y   yy
```

Merging all rows from `a` with only those that match from `b`: `a.merge(b, how='left')`

```
In [173]: a.merge(b, on='id', how='left')
Out[173]:
   id col1_x col2_x col1_y col2_y
0   1      a     aa    NaN    NaN
1   2      b     bb      x     xx
2   3      c     cc    NaN    NaN
3   4      d     dd      y     yy
4   5      e     ee    NaN    NaN
```

Merging all rows from `b` with only those that match from `a`: `b.merge(a, how='left')`

```
In [174]: b.merge(a, on='id', how='left')
Out[174]:
   id col1_x col2_x col1_y col2_y
0   2      x     xx      b     bb
1   4      y     yy      d     dd
```

or:

```
In [175]: a.merge(b, on='id', how='right')
Out[175]:
   id col1_x col2_x col1_y col2_y
0   2      b     bb      x     xx
1   4      d     dd      y     yy
```